# Uniqueness of singular vectors (Theorem 4.1 Trefethen & Bau)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, singular-values

I am looking for some clarifications in the uniqueness portion of the proof of Theorem 4.1 of Trefethen & Bau's *Numerical Linear Algebra*.

**The definition of the SVD and the proof exerpt from the text book are below.**

The question I have is this - why does the existence of $y$ such that $||y||=1$ and $||By||=\sigma_{1}$ imply that $y$ is a singular vector?

This does not seem to imply that $By = \sigma_{1}u_{1}$ (where $u_{1}$ is the left singular vector corresponding to $\sigma_{1}$ (or at least I can't see why the norm conditions imply that).

A clearer and more detailed explanation of this would be very appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to add some more context, at least the statement of theorem 4.1 and the definition of $B$.

Comment: This apparently makes use of the characterization that $v_2$ is a maximizer of $\|Av\|$ on the intersection of the unit sphere with the subspace orthogonal to $v_1$.

Comment: To make sense of $y$ you would need to include the previous discussion of what $V_1$ and $B$ are. Is there a discussion of the SVD in terms of linear algebra or is the whole introduction of the SVD based on the critical points of $x\mapsto \|Ax\|^2$ on the unit sphere?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, the discussion of the SVD is done through a linear algebra perspective. There is a discussion of the transformation of the sphere to the hyperellipse, but it doesn't seem to explain (at least not well enough for me) critical point perspective you've mentioned.